# Insert unique value into JSON payload to make API request using serenity bdd and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am really new to this, so maybe I am making an extremely simple mistake.

I have an automated test using Serenity and Java, making a POST request to an endpoint.

In the JSON payload there is a field  "inspectionId" which requires a unique value. If the value already exists in the database, the POST fails and you get a 400.

I know how to generate the unique ID in the java code, but I cant figure out how to put it into the payload before sending the POST request.

I am trying to figure out how to insert the newly generated UUID into the payload before making the post request.

In my code I have the JSON file, a POJO class, and all of the methods. Mostly using Restassured,

I know there must be an easy way to insert the UUID into the payload before sending, but I cant wrap my head around how or when to do it.
[post request step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cskfK.png)

Here is the code in case it's necessary

```
@Then("Send a POST request to the mobile api {string} version {double} for {string}")
    public void sendAPOSTRequestToUploadPaperworkApi(String api, double apiVersionValue, String value) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Double apiVersion = apiVersionValue;
        String apiType = value;

              if (apiType.equals("startInspection"))
        {
            StartInspection startInspection = testData.get(threadName).getStartInspection(); //Gets the POJO file

            String endpoint = variables.getProperty("ct_api_endpoint") + api; //creates the route to the endpoint

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); //formats dates
            mapper.setDateFormat(simpleDateFormat);

            String body = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(startInspection); //sets the body object

            Response response = ControlTowerOperators.ctPostARequestWithBody(endpoint, body, apiVersion); 

            testData.get(threadName).setResponse(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: we'd probably need to see more code here... ctPostARequestWithBody method in particular.... and include what "body" looks like.   It's worth noting that 400 is for bad request and is usually returned before any back-end code would be checking values against a DB.